# How to Customize Salesforce Community with our created visualforce page and remove standard functions?

Tags: community, community-builder

Actually i don't want to show standard tabs , search bar etc. I have my own Visualforce page which has also menus but when i call this page over community than standard menus and functions seems ugly.

So Please can any body tell me how to remove these Headers, Footers, Menus(Tabs), Search Bar from Community just wanted to call my single page in Community.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your apex:page tag to this one:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
```

That will remove the sidebar and the header of the standard community page.